# Javascript append + click remove them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got a question, what I have already solved, but it's just so annoying.

I have a js code, which is putting down some html code when a button is pushed with "append", and with that code I'm giving an id to an x button, and an id to the container element. I wanted to use these id-s to identify them with a click function, to remove the html code:

```
var num = 0;
$('.button').click(funcion(){
    num++;
    var code = '\
    <div class="container" id="text' + num + '">\
        <div id="x' + num + '">\
           x\
        </div>\ 
        Some stuff\
    </div>\
    ';

    $('.puthere').append(code);

    $('#x' + num).click(function(){
        $('#text' + num).remove();
    });
});
```

Now the annoying part is the click function on the x. What I would expect is, that this code would work somehow like this:
1st click on the "button" class element should give this code:

```
$('#x1').click(function(){
    $('#text1').remove();
});
```

after 2nd click I should have this:

```
$('#x1').click(function(){
    $('#text1').remove();
});

$('#x2').click(function(){
    $('#text2').remove();
});
```

instead what I'm getting after the 2nd click is this:

```
$('#x1').click(function(){
    $('#text2').remove();
});

$('#x2').click(function(){
    $('#text2').remove();
});
```

so it's always the last element what the x buttons want to remove. My question is, why can my "num" variable stay "1" at the #x1, but not at the #text1?

My solution was to address the parent element instead:

```
$('#x' + num).click(function(){
    $(this).parent('.container').remove();
});
```

I know, that there is the "live" function too, what I could use, and I wouldn't need to mess with id-s, but that just seems more heavy. Is that correct? Or I'm overcomplicating things too much without making it more efficent?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because num is global and you access it after you create second button. To fix this you can wrap your code with anonymouse self executing function:

```
(function(num) {
    $('#x' + num).click(function(){
        $('#text' + num).remove();
    });
})(num);
```

or better use only one click

```
$('.parent').on('click', '.container > div', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes I got confused by local and global variables where they are used. That anonymous self executing function helps a lot, it worked, and I will probably use it more often now, that I know what it does!